# How can I show that two linearly independent vectors are not orthogonal?

Tags: calculus, vectors, orthogonality, independence

How can I show that

> Two linearly independent vectors are not orthogonal?

This is my thought process:

Two linearly independent vectors $u$ and $v$.

$ c_1u_1+c_2u_2+...+c_nu_n=0$

$ c_1v_1+c_2v_2+...+c_nv_n=0$

From here I need to take the inner product of $u$ and $v$ but that's where I'm stuck. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: $u,v$ are independent means that $au + bv = 0$ implies that $a = b = 0$. They are orthogonal only if $\langle u, v \rangle = 0$.

What do you mean stuck? The only thing you can say generally about two lin. ind. orthogonal vectors is that $\langle u, v \rangle \neq 0$

Comment: “Two linearly independent vectors u and v. c_1u_1+c_2u_2+...+c_nu_n=0 c_1v_1+c_2v_2+...+c_nv_n=0”  I am not sure what this means.  It looks like you are applying one part of the definition of linear independence for a *set* of vectors to the components of a *single* vector, twice.  (But then, also, not applying the conclusion?)  This also seems to be within the context of a larger problem; better to ask a question about that problem instead of this confusing case.

Comment: The two basis vectors $e_1$ and $e_2$ of the standard basis of ${\mathbb R}^2$ are linearly independent and at the same time orthogonal.

Comment: I think you need to provide more context for the claim that you’re trying to prove, since it’s not true in general. Indeed, *every* pair of orthogonal vectors is also linearly independent.